# Sharing records using criteria based sharing rules

Tags: sharing, role-hierarchy, roles, criteria-based-sharing

Made OWD for Contact as Private and defined 2 criteria based sharing rules

If brand = abc.. share this contact with Role A and its subordinates

If brand = def.. share this contact with Role B and its subordinates
(There are no other workflows or record types on contact)

Did the same for account. It worked perfectly. 
But for contact unable to get this working. I, as a system admin created a contact with brand = abc, logged in as user under one of the role of Role A, but unable to view this contact.

Please note that contacts will have no accounts populated

Comment: @mohith, I thought of editing the original post.. but made some changes.. like removed workflow and record types so created new post..

Comment: raise case with support now .I have retracted closed vote

Comment: I tried contacting them.. seems like admin team will not be available for support till monday and I have a small demo of this POC on monday !

Comment: Try in another sandbox or org?

Comment: Aggain the same problem in another org as well but Question # 61520 .. answer by richard is very close to my issue...

Comment: Are those contacts without accounts?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Here is the design of account and contact in my org: account and contact are almost isolate and are connected using junction object AccountContacts. Contacts donot have account populated on them but can have multiple accountcontacts associated to a single contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot share private contacts currently. Check the success community forum.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_sharing.htm&language=en

You cannot share contacts without accounts .just for visibility sake you may assign a dummy account to your contacts

Comment: A simple Contact insert trigger can take care of automatically creating an Account for each Contact. The free Non-Profit Starter Pack app also includes functionality to either make 1-to-1 Accounts or 1 "Individual" Account that all Contacts will be assigned to.